# How to change the link on the logo at the menu?

Tags: menus, links, code, logo

I'm working on my site, it been done with a site builder so the logo on the menu has a default link to my homepage, but I need to change this link so it goes to another page instead of the default homepage.

On this builder there's a place to add custom CSS on every page, so even though I'm not an expert on coding I can try to add the right code to each page that needs this, all I need is the coding to add which I cant write.

Thanks

Comment: You can’t change links with CSS. If you need support with your theme/site builder you should contact it’s author. Support for 3rd-party themes and plugins is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do it with Jquery, To set the href attribute, use the following code:

```
$('selector a').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

For example:

```
$('.logo a').attr('href','http://example.com');
```